# In what order did Thanos proceed at the beginning of "Endgame"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the beginning of *Avengers: Endgame*, in what order did Thanos destroy the Infinity Stones? What Stone would he destroy last?

Or could he use two Stones at the same time and have them destroy one another?

Comment: haven't it shown in the movie?

Comment: the details was never revealed

Comment: I assumed he used 6 stones at the same time to have them destroy one another.  I suppose he could have unsnapped Scarlet Witch, and used the 6 to destroy all but the Mind Stone, then told Scarlet Witch if she destroyed the Mind Stone he'd take her back to earth.  But that would be needlessly circuitous, and Scarlet Witch could kick his ass.

Answer (score 12):

The Avengers track Thanos down by the energy signature emitted by the destruction of the stones, which is described as similar or comparable to the one emitted during the snap. Additionally, we see that the act was powerful enough to damage Thanos, whereas the snap left the (admittedly armored) Thanos whole.

From this, I think it's a safe assumption that destroying the stones required the *combined* power of all stones at once, similar to the expenditure of energy required for the snap, and perhaps even more so.

I saw no indication or reason to believe they were destroyed individually.

Comment: i guessed that the time stone wasn't really destroyed, like in the comics.

Comment: The MCU is different enough from the comics in all aspects (plot, powers, characters) that one should never assume that comic plot lines will transfer to the films.

Comment: They were surely destroyed all at once. Because how exactly do you want to destroy a single stone as Thanos with no technology whatsoever and without another stone to do so?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: that was why the OP proposed "the last two stones destroyed each other", but I see no reason to assume that, as opposed to one massive blast.

Comment: Thanos' specific quote is "I used the Stones to destroy the Stones". I assumed this to mean he used all six at once, to destroy all six at once.